# Testing with Rocket and Diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I am trying to work on a web app with `Diesel` and `Rocket`, by following the [rocket guide](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/introduction/). I have not able to understand how to do testing of this app.

```
//in main.rs

#[database("my_db")]
struct PgDbConn(diesel::PgConnection);

#[post("/users", format="application/json", data="<user_info>")]
fn create_new_user(conn: PgDbConn, user_info: Json<NewUser>) {
    use schema::users;
    diesel::insert_into(users::table).values(&*user_info).execute(&*conn).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .attach(PgDbConn::fairing())
        .mount("/", routes![create_new_user])
        .launch();
}
```

```
// in test.rs

use crate::PgDbConn;

#[test]
fn test_user_creation() {
    let rocket = rocket::ignite().attach(PgDbConn::fairing());
    let client = Client::new(rocket).unwrap();
    let response = client
        .post("/users")
        .header(ContentType::JSON)
        .body(r#"{"username": "xyz", "email": "temp@abc.com"}"#)
        .dispatch();
    assert_eq!(response.status(), Status::Ok);
}
```

But this modifies the database. How can I make sure that the test does not alter the database.

I tried to create two database and use them in the following way(I am not sure if this is recommended)

```
#[cfg(test)]
#[database("test_db")]
struct PgDbConn(diesel::PgConnection);

#[cfg(not(test))]
#[database("live_db")]
struct PgDbConn(diesel::PgConnection);
```

Now I thought I can use the `test_transaction` method of the `diesel::connection::Connection` trait in the following way:-

```
use crate::PgDbConn;

#[test]
fn test_user_creation() {
    // !!This statment is wrong as PgDbConn is an Fn object instead of a struct
    // !!I am not sure how it works but it seems that this Fn object is resolved 
    // !!into struct only when used as a Request Guard
    let conn = PgDbConn;
    
    // Deref trait for PgDbConn is implemented, So I thought that dereferencing 
    // it will return a diesel::PgConnection
    (*conn).test_transaction::<_, (), _>(|| {
        let rocket = rocket::ignite().attach(PgDbConn::fairing());
        let client = Client::new(rocket).unwrap();
        let response = client
            .post("/users")
            .header(ContentType::JSON)
            .body(r#"{"username": "Tushar", "email": "temp@abc.com"}"#)
            .dispatch();
        assert_eq!(response.status(), Status::Ok);
        Ok(())
    });
}
```

The above code obviously fails to compile. Is there a way to resolve this `Fn` object into the struct and obtain the `PgConnection` in it. And I am not even sure if this is the right to way to do things.

Is there a recommended way to do testing while using both `Rocket` and `Diesel`?

Answer (score 1):

This will fundamentally not work as you imagined there, as `conn` will be a different connection than whatever rocket generates for you. The test_transaction pattern assumes that you use the same connection for everything.

Comment: Yes, after a bit more asking, I came to know that the route handler will open a separate connection and will commit the test data into the database; and hence it does not make sense to use `test_transaction`. So Is there no way by which we can test if the data is being correctly entered into the database AND restore the database to the previous state at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It's very late and I have no idea if it's still a valid question, but for anyone looking for a solution: this guide put me in the right direction.

You basically set up a test context which generates a separate database for each test where you generate the context.
[Test Context Guide](https://snoozetime.github.io/2019/06/16/integration-test-diesel.html)https://snoozetime.github.io/2019/06/16/integration-test-diesel.html

Comment: Please note that content which is only linked is not considered part of an answer on StackOverflow. What remains is ... extremely brief ... You might want to treat this as a link-only answer, I will provide the standardised comment to help you with that.

Comment: mocrsteel, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. First answer so I'll look to improve that one.